# Setting own mongoose schema _id property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I've found a number of examples showing the ability to set your own `_id` property to something other than the default ObjectId in a mongoose schema:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String
});
```

A few questions I have:

1) Does this auto increment and handle everything else for me? The only examples I've seen don't show any additional code to ensure this a unique and incremented key in MongoDB.

2) This doesn't seem work for me. When I remove the `_id` from the schema, I get documents posting correctly as expected, but when I add it (`_id: Number`), nothing gets added to the collection, and Postman returns just an empty object `{}`. Here's the relevant code:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String
});

var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

app.get("/person", function (req, res) {
    Person.find(function (err, people) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(people)
        }
    });
});

app.post("/person", function(req, res) {
    var newPerson = new Person(req.body);

    newPerson.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(newPerson);
        }
    });
});
```

A POST request returns `{}`, and neither the collection nor document are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include an `_id` field in your schema definition, when you insert a document you must supply it with your own manually generated `_id`. If you don't, the document will not get inserted.

Alternatively, if you do not include an `_id` field in your schema definition, Mongoose will create this for you automatically, when the document is inserted, and it will be of type `ObjectId` (which is the default way that MongoDB sets the `_id` field on documents).

Comment: This makes sense. Now I just have to look up some best practices for creating your own `id` property and maintaining the correct increments, etc...